# AWS Document DB MultiRegion replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I know that the AWS DocumentDB doesnot support multiregion replication even the snapshot cannot be shared across regions.

Please suggest how we can manually do the replication

Answer (score 2):

Sam,
AWS released cross-region snapshot copy today (7/10/20), so that should get you what you need. Good luck.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/amazon-documentdb-support-cross-region-snapshot-copy/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the feedback, Sam. A couple of options are to use [change streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change-streams.html) + Lambda/worker to replicate the data or to take take backups to S3 with mongodump and utilize [S3's cross-region replication capabilities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon DocumentDB now supports global clusters. The primary cluster supports writes and read-scaling, up to 5 regions can be added as read-only, see https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/global-clusters/